# What does this Android process mean? android:process=":sandboxed_process10

Tags: android, accessibility, sandbox, android-11, motorola-droid

I have a Motorola G6 2022 . It is showing this code all the time ad I thought maybe I should ask thank you.

Comment: Hello. I don’t see why this would be tagged with accessibility?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.